# Variable returns boolean false w/var_dump()

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am trying to feed in a tax_query argument with a variable pulling from a Custom Field.  Yet nothing is returned.  I did a var_dump on my variable and it keeps returning "boolean:False".  So I thought maybe I needed to run a loop (my custom field is a sub_field of a group), and then var_dump returns nothing at all.  I'm fairly new to WP/PHP development, not sure what's going on here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
if(have_rows('wine_profile')) : 
    while(have_rows('wine_profile')) : the_row();

$label = get_sub_field("taxonomy_label");
var_dump($label);

$wineProfiles = new WP_Query(array(

    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type'   => 'wines',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'labels',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $label
        )
    ),

    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'ID'

));
if ($wineProfiles->have_posts()) : while ($wineProfiles->have_posts()) : $wineProfiles->the_post();
        get_template_part('includes/component', 'colorBlockLg');
        get_template_part('includes/component', 'profile');
?>

<?php endwhile;
endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: If it is returning false, that means it's not finding anything. Make sure that 'taxonomy_label' is the correct name. You could also look to `var_dump('wine_profile')` to see what comes from that.

Comment: Thanks for the response Luke.  'wine_profile' is a custom field group, so I tried 
$wine = get_field('wine_profile') ,  var_dump($wine) and getting 'null' from that.

Comment: It's confusing because in the wp admin I can see the values, but they're not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -

```
$label = get_sub_field("taxonomy_label",get_the_ID());
var_dump($label);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you haven't started post loop!

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Put your code here       //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
``
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried doing that too.  The field is part of a group, so I used the 'have rows' loop instead, but then nothing shows up at all for either type of loop.